# Оставить строки с максимальным значением в столбце

Tags: mysql, sql

Практикуюсь на базе данных [Northwind в MySQL](http://downloads.alphasoftware.com/a5v12Download/northwindmysql.zip).
Написал следующий запрос:

```
select ShipCountry,
       ProductName,
       sum(Quantity) as TotalQuantity,
       sum(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice * (1 - od.Discount)) as TotalSpendings
    from orders o
    join `order details` od on o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    join products p on od.ProductID = p.ProductID
    group by ShipCountry, ProductName
```

Который выводит такой результат:
[image: Результат запроса]

Как правильно переписать запрос так, чтобы вывести только те продукты в разрезе каждой из стран, которых было продано больше всего (оставить одну единственную строку по каждой стране с наибольшим значением `TotalQuantity`)?
Например, вместо двух `Germany` из скриншота должна быть только одна строка `Germany` с `TotalQuantity` = 155.
В голову приходит использование `order by` или `max()`, но не понимаю как это написать чтобы не возникало ошибок.

Comment: Да как обычно... ROW_NUMBER() в CTE и отбор первых в основном запросе.

Comment: @Akina откуда уверенность что mysql 8 ?

Comment: @teran Если версия не указана - имею право считать, что версия актуальная. Если нет - автор уточнит. Впрочем, если за 11 часов автор не почесался - то либо его это устроило, либо ему решение нафиг не нужно.